# Trying to call class method from a Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, invocable-method

So my class has

```
global class SendQueue{
@InvocableMethod
public static void send(List<ListRequests> requests)
{...}
global class ListRequests{
@InvocableVariable(required=True)
public Id ownerID;
 }
}
```

My Trigger

```
trigger CallBack on Task (before insert) {
SendQueue.ListRequests listVars = new SendQueue.ListRequests();
List<listVars> requests = new listVars();
....
SendQueue.send(); //trying to call the send function in the class
}
```

When trying to compile the trigger, there is an error of Invalid type:listVars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is compile error because you are trying to declare variable `requests` of incorrect type. `List` is container and this container should have some type. For example, `List<String>`, `List<SObject>` etc. `List<listVars>` is icorrect if you don't have `listVars` class in your namespace.

Comment: When I initialize List<SendQueue.ListRequests> listVars = new SendQueue.Requests();  I get an error illegal assisnment from SendQueue.ListRequests to List<SendQueue.ListRequests>

Comment: Can you add more details about what do you want to do with that trigger, cause I can only guess now.  Maybe you want to have the following line List<SendQueue.ListRequests> requests = new List<SendQueue.ListRequests>();  .Here is a trailhead about Apex. Topic about containers will be useful https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_database/units/apex_database_intro